# Match all string followed by asterisk

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Basically I'm creating a simple Interpreter for our compiler course. Of course this is not a homework-type question.

Anything that is followed by an asterisks is considered a comment provided that it is not part of the string. I have an escape character in my Interpreter which are brackets.

These are sample syntax for my interpreter

```
* hello world
OUTPUT: "This is asterisk [*]" * outputs string
OUTPUT: "This is asterisk *"  * outputs string produces syntax error
x = "[*]" & "hello" & "[*]*]" this is already comment which produces syntax error
```

when I try to run this `Regex`

```
[^\[]\*.*
```

It matches with the following:

```
* hello world
 * outputs string
 *"  * outputs string produces syntax error
]*]" this is already comment which produces syntax error
```

My question is, why did the `regex` "*eats*" one character before? Wherein I already need

```
* hello world
* outputs string
*"  * outputs string produces syntax error
*]" this is already comment which produces syntax error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use zero width assertions to stop capturing the condition you just want to match, and
not "eat" :

`(?<=[^\[])\*.*`

`(?<=REGEX_CONDITION)` ensures that matching is done, but the matched part ( NOT A "[" in your case) is not included in the matched result.

Demo : http://regexr.com?32b99

Edit: to make it fully working, I just added or condition on it

```
(?<=[^\[])\*.*|^\*.*
```

Comment: Why does assertion needs here? I'll try if it work on other cases. I'll be back.

Comment: @DerekFloss Normal matching means "MATCH AND CAPTURE, assertion means "MATCH, BUT DO NOT CAPTURE" . You want to check that character before "*" is not a "[", but you would not want to include that character i.e. " ", or "]" etc in your final match

Comment: why is `* hello world` not included?

Answer (score 0):

Try using groups and use the group value as in `[^\[](\*.*)`